# How to change ajax load for magento2 ui_component form

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have created a ui_component form in magento custom module. Below is my ui_component file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grid</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
          ...
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item> 
    </argument>
    ...
</form>
```

Uisng this my form loading using ajax after page load , But I want to load form on page load.

Is it possible in magento2 or for this I have to create my own template? If so then How to do?

Comment: please add your code for fieldsets